# Windows Firewall : Change log file location using batch

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, firewall

I am looking for a way to be able to change the log file location for the firewall using the command-line, ultimately to put it in a batch file.

I know the log can be enabled and configured from the UI in "Advanced Firewall Settings", but nowhere could I find if it was possible of doing it from command line.

[MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947815(v=ws.10).aspx) documentation is only explaining it from UI and all the info I can gather is explaining how to do it from UI as well.

Comment: If you can upgrade to a newer powershell version you will be able to manage the firewall that way. [Set-NetFirewallProfile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554896(v=wps.630).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Spokey, but unfortunately I have no access to PowerShell as it is actually Windows Embedded Standard 7, and PowerShell components have not been installed on the devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to find documentation from Microsoft.

Using `netsh advfirewall`, it is possible to modify the logging settings.

Here is the link to the Article : [How to use the "netsh advfirewall firewall" context instead of the "netsh firewall" context to control Windows Firewall behavior in Windows Server 2008 and in Windows Vista](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947709)

You need to scroll down to **Example 5: Set Logging**. Here are the commands to enter :

```
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile logging filename %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile logging maxfilesize 4096
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile logging droppedconnections enable
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile logging allowedconnections enable
```